# Dispatcher has no subscribers error for ftp

Tags: spring-integration

I have a file dropped at the ftp location which should be picked up by ftp-inbound-adapter. This file is saved to a local-directory. This local-directory is in turn polled by spring file-inbound-adapter. The filenamegenerator bean is used in the file-inbound-adapter and decides the destination dynamically. I have also posted another question about the file in the local-directory not being deleted. This is the problem I am facing.
This is a my entire configuration

```
        <util:properties id="someid" location="classpath:config/config.properties"/>
        <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.dms" />
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix">
                <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
            </property>
            <property name="suffix">
                <value>.jsp</value>
            </property>
        </bean>
         <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config/jdbc.properties,classpath:config/config.properties,classpath:config/ftp.properties"/>
          <bean id="dataSource"
            class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
            >
            <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
            <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
            <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
            <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
            </bean>
         <bean id="sessionFactory"
                class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

                <property name="dataSource">
                      <ref bean="dataSource" />
                </property>

                <property name="hibernateProperties">
                      <props>
                            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
                            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">${hibernate.generate_statistics}</prop>
                      </props>
                </property>
                <property name="packagesToScan">
                <list>
                    <value>com.dms.entity</value>
                </list>
            </property>
                </bean>
                <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

         <bean id="multipartResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">

             <!-- setting maximum upload size -->
            <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10485760" />

        </bean>
        <!-- scheduler to pickup temp folder files to permanent location -->

        <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
                 <property name="triggers">
                        <list>
                             <ref bean="simpleTrigger" /> 

                        </list>
                 </property>
          </bean>
         <bean id="dmsFilesDetectionJob" class="com.dms.scheduler.job.DMSFilesDetectionJob">

         </bean>
         <bean id="dmsFilesDetectionJobDetail" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
            <property name="targetObject" ref="dmsFilesDetectionJob" />
            <property name="targetMethod" value="pollTempFolder" />
            <property name="concurrent" value="false" />
         </bean>
        <bean id="simpleTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
            <property name="jobDetail" ref="dmsFilesDetectionJobDetail" />
            <!-- <property name="cronExpression" value="1 * * * * ?" /> --> 
            <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0/1 * * * ?" /> 
         </bean>

      <bean id="fileNameGenerator" class="com.dms.util.FileNameGenerator"/>   
        <int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filesIn" directory="file:${paths.root}" channel="abc" filter="compositeFilter" >
            <int:poller id="poller" fixed-delay="5000" />

        </int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>
        <int:channel id="abc"/>
        <bean id="compositeFilter" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.CompositeFileListFilter">
            <constructor-arg>
                <list>
                    <!-- Ensures that the file is whole before processing it -->
                    <bean class="com.dms.util.CustomFileFilter"/>
                    <!-- Ensures files are picked up only once from the directory -->
                    <bean class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.AcceptOnceFileListFilter" />
                </list>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean> 
        <int-file:outbound-channel-adapter channel="abc" id="filesOut"
            directory-expression="@outPathBean.getPath()"
            delete-source-files="true" filename-generator="fileNameGenerator" />
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
            <property name="messageConverters">
                <list>
                    <ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
        <bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
         <!-- <property name="prefixJson" value="false"/> -->
          <!-- <property name="objectMapper">
                <bean class="com.dms.util.HibernateAwareObjectMapper" />
            </property> -->
            <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json"/>
        </bean>   
        <bean id="ftpClientFactory"
        class="org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.DefaultFtpSessionFactory">
        <property name="host" value="${ftp.ip}"/>
        <property name="port" value="${ftp.port}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${ftp.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${ftp.password}"/>
        <property name="clientMode" value="0"/>
        <property name="fileType" value="2"/>
        <property name="bufferSize" value="100000"/>
    </bean>
            <int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter id="ftpOutbound"
    channel="ftpChannel"
    session-factory="ftpClientFactory"
    charset="UTF-8"
    remote-file-separator="/"
    auto-create-directory="true"
    remote-directory="." 
    use-temporary-file-name="true"
   auto-startup="true" 
    />  
<int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="ftpInbound"
    channel="ftpChannel"
    session-factory="ftpClientFactory"
    charset="UTF-8"
    local-directory="file:${paths.root}"
    delete-remote-files="true"
    temporary-file-suffix=".writing"
    remote-directory="."
    filename-pattern="${file.char}*${file.char}"

    preserve-timestamp="true"
     auto-startup="true">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="1000"/>
</int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
        <int:channel id="ftpChannel" />
```

This is the error I am getting

```
  18:02:34.655 E|LoggingHandler                          |org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext:/DMS/DMS-dispatcher.ftpChannel'.
```

This exception does not appear everytime.
As you can see I have added auto-startup="true". Have used unique id's for both the channels as well as adapters. Please let me know what is wrong here!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all your integration flow ins't clear. But I see that your issue is for this

```
<int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="ftpInbound" channel="ftpChannel"
```

Where there is really no one who is subscribed to that `ftpChannel` `SubscribableChannel`.

So, that adapter starts his work and sends message to that channel, but ... `Dispatcher has no subscribers`.

Try to fix that issue and figure out how to go ahead.

**EDIT**

Not sure what you have found in my answer so bad that it forced you to downvote it. Anyway.

There was some `phase` problem [before](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3475), but as you see it has been fixed in the version `4.1`.

So, to reach the immediate fix right now you should do this:

```
phase="0x7fffffff" // Integer.MAX_VALUE
```

by default `phase` is `0`, so the inbound channel adapter may start before outbound channel adapter.

Or just upgrade to the latest [Spring Integration](http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/)!

Comment: Should there be a single channel with ftpinbound adapter reading from it and ftp outbound writing to it?

Comment: This exception is not consistent either. Now it is running without any problem

Comment: That's great that you fixed an issues on your won. If my answer was helpful, please, accept it to mark the question as closed.

Comment: I have edited the q to add my complete configuration as you said the flow was unclear. I have also changed it to use the same channel for both inbound as well as outbound. Please let me know if I must change anything in the configuration. I will observe the app for some runs and then conclude that the channel change was the solution.

Comment: Please, find an `EDIT` in my answer. Hope that is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to deal with this but with a file inbound-channel-adapter. The issue is intermittent, and only at startup. I think adapters with pollers can start pulling in messages before Spring Integration has fully initialized.

My fix is to disable the adapter at startup. The details of the adapter are not so important, other than it has an id and is set to not autostart:

```
  <!--
    Read files from an "inbox" directory, placing them on an "inbox" channel...
  -->

  <int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="inboxScanner"
                                    directory="$import{inbox}"
                                    auto-create-directory="true"
                                    channel="fileInbox"
                                    prevent-duplicates="false"
                                    auto-startup="false">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="$import{inbox.scan.rate.seconds}"
                time-unit="SECONDS"
                max-messages-per-poll="$import{inbox.max.imports.per.scan}"/>
  </int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

I then tap into Spring's application lifecycle events, and once the application context is finished being created (or refreshed), I tell the adapter to start:

```
  <!--
    Only start the scanner after the application has finished initializing...
  -->

  <int-event:inbound-channel-adapter event-types="org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent"
                                 channel="contextRefreshEvents"/>

  <int:publish-subscribe-channel id="contextRefreshEvents"/>

  <int:outbound-channel-adapter channel="contextRefreshEvents"
                                expression="@inboxScanner.start()" />
```

The "event" components are from spring-integration-event.

Comment: Please, take a look into `EDIT` in my answer. Your solution is good, but there is much simpler trick - tweak a `phase`.

Comment: Good to know. I'll leave my answer here, but it sounds like the real answer is to upgrade! Thanks for pointing this out :-)